# SpriteKit Swift 4 changing all AnchorPoints

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, swift4, anchorpoint

How can I in Xcode, Swift 4 in SpriteKit change anchor points of all objects located in my GameView they are on default set to x: 0,5 y: 0,5 (meaning that the anchor point is in the half of the height and in the half of the width of an object) and I can easily change anchor point of an single object but how can make it apply to all objects in GameScene and also to ones I will add in the future?